# What kind of mic can be used for double bass?

Tags: microphone, recording

I want to record double bass, so I need a microphone. What type mic can be used for recording double bass?

I interested in micing multiple instrument is there any overview table which shows which mic can be used to record a given instrument?

Answer (score 2):

You **can** use any microphone for any instrument. However which one you use will depend on your specifics - is the instrument going to be moving, do you want to be very directional to just record one out of an orchestra, do you want an omnidirectional mic to record a group of instruments?

Do you want to record the vibration of the wood through a contact mic, the string vibration through a piezo pickup, or the air vibration using a microphone attached to the instrument or fixed to a stand?

These are the most important questions you need to answer - and then of course you'll end up choosing based on cost :-)